# Azure Kubernetes sample - Waiting for cluster initialization

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am trying out the Kubernetes setup from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/azure.md) The problem is that it hangs  with the following output :

> Waiting for cluster initialization.

This will continually check to see if the API for kubernetes is reachable.
  This might loop forever if there was some uncaught error during start
  up.

...................................................................................................................................................................

And it just hangs there?

Comment: same here, have you been able to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/chanezon/azure-linux/tree/master/coreos/kubernetes Kubernetes for GIT is currently broken, I also wasnt able to get it running unfortunately :(